# Rate limit http requests based on host address

Tags: go, rate-limiting

I have developed a HTTP server using Go. Now I would like to implement a rate limiter, so that I can check if a HTTP request from a particular IP is sending more than 10 HTTP requests in 1 min, I can put that IP in a block list for some time say (1 hr) and in the meantime is the same subscriber is sending requests while he/she was in blocking period I would be sending 429 error response from HTTP server.

I have written a code for this, but in this am able to block the IP addresses, but in that its unblocking all the IP's after 1 hr of time. I am expecting first come first unblock.

```
Package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./html/"))
    http.Handle("/", fs)
    log.Println("Listening..")
    go clearLastRequestsIPs()
    go clearBlockedIPs()
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", middleware(nil))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

// Stores last requests IPs
var lastRequestsIPs []string

// Block IP for 1 hours
var blockedIPs []string

func middleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ipAddr := strings.Split(r.RemoteAddr, ":")[0]
        if existsBlockedIP(ipAddr) {
            http.Error(w, "", http.StatusTooManyRequests)
            return
        }
        // how many requests the current IP made in last 5 mins
        requestCounter := 0
        for _, ip := range lastRequestsIPs {
            if ip == ipAddr {
                requestCounter++
            }
        }
        if requestCounter >= 1000 {
            blockedIPs = append(blockedIPs, ipAddr)
            http.Error(w, "", http.StatusTooManyRequests)
            return
        }
        lastRequestsIPs = append(lastRequestsIPs, ipAddr)

        if next == nil {
            http.DefaultServeMux.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func existsBlockedIP(ipAddr string) bool {
    for _, ip := range blockedIPs {
        if ip == ipAddr {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func existsLastRequest(ipAddr string) bool {
    for _, ip := range lastRequestsIPs {
        if ip == ipAddr {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

// Clears lastRequestsIPs array every 1 hrs
func clearLastRequestsIPs() {
    for {
        lastRequestsIPs = []string{}
        time.Sleep(time.Hour * 1)
    }
}

// Clears blockedIPs array every 1 hours
func clearBlockedIPs() {
    for {
        blockedIPs = []string{}
        time.Sleep(time.Hour * 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren‘t storing the time at which an IP was blocked or is supposed to be unblocked. Create a type consisting of the IP and the unblock time. Put newly blocked IPs into an array of that type (which btw should be guarded via a mutex!) and iterate over said array every few seconds, removing the blocked IPs which expired. A very naive approach, but it should work. The proper option would be to set a time.Timer for each blocked IP, removing it after 1h. You might want to persist the blocked IPs, too, in case of a server restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some middleware like this:

```
type Limiter struct {
    ipCount map[string]int
    sync.Mutex
}

var limiter Limiter
func init() {
    limiter.ipCount = make(map[string]int)
}

func limit(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Get the IP address for the current user.
    ip, _, err := net.SplitHostPort(r.RemoteAddr)
    if err != nil {
      log.Println(err.Error())
      http.Error(w, "Internal Server Error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
      return
    }

    // Get the # of times the visitor has visited in the last 60 seconds
    limiter.Lock()
    count, ok := limiter.ipCount[ip]
    if !ok {
        limiter.ipCount[ip] = 0
    }
    if count > 10 {
      limiter.Unlock()
      http.Error(w, http.StatusText(429), http.StatusTooManyRequests)
      return
    } else {
        limiter.ipCount[ip]++
    }
    time.AfterFunc(time.Second * 60, func() {
        limiter.Lock()
        limiter.ipCount[ip]--
        limiter.Unlock()
    })
    if limiter.ipCount[ip] == 10 {
        // set it to 20 so the decrement timers will only decrease it to
        // 10, and they stay blocked until the next timer resets it to 0
        limiter.ipCount[ip] = 20
        time.AfterFunc(time.Hour, func() {
            limiter.Lock()
            limiter.ipCount[ip] = 0
            limiter.Unlock()
        })
    }
    limiter.Unlock()
    next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
  })
}
```

Comment: Mismatched map and int error at this "if limiter.ipCount == 10 {"

Answer (score -1):

Use `rate.NewLimiter()` from golang.org/x/time/rate package.